# Filling The Bitmap With An Image

Tags: java, android, bitmap, crop

I want to crop the detected object with yolo in android.

```
if ((int)location.left > 0 && (int)location.top > 0 && ((int)location.left + (int)location.width()) < croppedBitmap.getWidth()
                                    && ((int)location.top + (int)location.height()) < croppedBitmap.getHeight()  ) {
 
                                mycroppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(croppedBitmap,
                                        (int) location.left,
                                        (int) location.top,
                                        (int) location.width(),
                                        (int) location.height()
                      );

                                
         mycroppedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mycroppedBitmap, TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZEE, TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZEE, true);
```

At first it does not go inside the if block, the image in the bitmap is transparent,

this line of code works and recaptures image.

```
 rgbFrameBitmap.setPixels(getRgbBytes(), 0, previewWidth, 0, 0, previewWidth, previewHeight);
```

the second time it doesn't enter again, the bitmap looks black.

on the third it fills up with the bitmap image. This is good. But it doesn't go inside the if block.
captures the picture again

```
  rgbFrameBitmap.setPixels(getRgbBytes(), 0, previewWidth, 0, 0, previewWidth, previewHeight);
```

What should I do so that when the bitmap is filled with the image it goes inside the if block? for crop. I would love any help or advice :) , thanks.

[image: ex]

Answer (score 0):

I would assume if it is validating size against `croppedBitmap`, then after first pass the bitmap gets cropped the mentioned dimensions and the condition `<` always fails instead you should use `<=`

```
if ((int)location.left > 0 && (int)location.top > 0 
      && ((int)location.left + (int)location.width()) <= croppedBitmap.getWidth()
      && ((int)location.top + (int)location.height()) <= croppedBitmap.getHeight()  ) {
   // logic goes here
   // After first the height is set to (int)location.top + (int)location.height(), 
   // so by validating with <= it should work
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer @Rajan Kali. I used with <=. After coming to the if block it didn't go into it. Program returned to this line : rgbFrameBitmap.setPixels(getRgbBytes(), 0, previewWidth, 0, 0, previewWidth, previewHeight);

Comment: Cropping for the yolo first. Then I try to crop again for the other model(200x200) OrijinalImage->croppedBitmap(416x416) ->myCroppedBitmap(200x200)